# The pandas dataframe do not get updated based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe and I need to update a column based on a condition (I'm trying to label text using Microsoft azure API and then save the label back to the original data frame so that later I can calculate the accuracy). But weirdly the data frame does not get updated!!

This is a sample code:

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient


key = "key"
endpoint = "https://endpoint"

text_analytics_client = TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint=endpoint,   credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'text': ['im ok', 'you arent ok', 'its fine'],
                   'Sentiment':['positive', 'negative', 'neutral']})
n = 10

for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n):
    result = text_analytics_client.analyze_sentiment(df.iloc[i:i + n].to_dict('records'))
######in case you do not have azure credentials to get this code run, the out of the result is like this:
######[AnalyzeSentimentResult(id=2, sentiment=negative, warnings= [], statistics=None, confidence_scores=SentimentConfidenceScores(positive=0.01, neutral=0.16, negative=0.83), sentences=[SentenceSentiment(text=you arent ok, sentiment=negative, confidence_scores=SentimentConfidenceScores(positive=0.01, neutral=0.16, negative=0.83), length=12, offset=0, mined_opinions=[])], is_error=False), AnalyzeSentimentResult(id=3, sentiment=positive, warnings=[], statistics=None, confidence_scores=SentimentConfidenceScores(positive=0.98, neutral=0.01, negative=0.01), sentences=[SentenceSentiment(text=its fine, sentiment=positive, confidence_scores=SentimentConfidenceScores(positive=0.98, neutral=0.01, negative=0.01), length=8, offset=0, mined_opinions=[])], is_error=False)]

    for idx, doc in enumerate(result):
        print(doc.sentiment) ##this will print out a value
        id_res = result[idx]['id']
        #print(id_res) this will print out the correct id
        df.loc[df.id == id_res, 'label'] = doc.sentiment
        print(df) ### but here when the dataframe is printed the label column is NAN
```

I have searched and find multiple links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274628/updating-values-of-pandas-dataframe-on-condition), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368151/pandas-dataframe-doesnt-update-column-value-under-condition) or [this](https://www.easytweaks.com/update-values-dataframe-pandas-python/). In all three examples they are doing the same thing as me but my dataframe do not get updated and this is the result I get:

```
   id          text   Sentiment label
0   1         im ok  positive   NaN
1   2  you arent ok  negative   NaN
2   3      its fine   neutral   NaN
```

**details**

Im adding some details so that it may help. As I commented in the code `res_result` has a correct id. When I replace this `df.loc[df.id == id_res, 'label']` with `df.loc[df.id == 1, 'label']` it successfully updated that rows but otherwise it does not get updated!!!!

Appreciate any input on how to fix this.

Comment: You may first want to set a default "label" first in `df`, before entering the nested loop. You're now assigning a new column, while selecting rows at the same time.

Comment: @9769953 thanks for the input but I have done that already and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line here:

```
df.loc[df.id == id_res, 'label'] = doc.sentiment
```

`df.id` is type int and `id_res` is type string. If you convert `id_res` to int then this will be a valid comparison and you'll get the output you're looking for:

```
df.loc[df.id == int(id_res), 'label'] = doc.sentiment
```

Output:

```
   id          text Sentiment     label
0   1         im ok  positive   neutral
1   2  you arent ok  negative  negative
2   3      its fine   neutral  positive
```